# Fastest way to "unpack' a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hope the title is not misleading.
I load an Excel file in a pandas dataframe as usual

```py
df = pd.read_excel('complete.xlsx')
```

and this is what's inside (usually is already ordered - this is a really small sample)

```py
df
Out[21]: 
    Country       City First Name  Last Name  Ref
0   England     London       John      Smith   34
1   England     London       Bill       Owen  332
2   England   Brighton        Max      Crowe   25
3   England   Brighton      Steve      Grant   55
4    France      Paris     Roland      Tomas   44
5    France      Paris    Anatole     Donnet  534
6    France       Lyon     Paulin     Botrel  234
7     Spain     Madrid      Oriol  Abarquero   34
8     Spain     Madrid    Alberto    Olloqui  534
9     Spain  Barcelona      Ander     Moreno  254
10    Spain  Barcelona      Cesar     Aranda  222
```

what I need to do is automating an export of the data creating a sqlite db for every country, (i.e. 'England.sqlite') which will contain a table for evey city (i.e. London and Brighton) and every table will have the related personnel info.

The sqlite is not a problem, I'm only trying to figure how to "unpack" the dataframe in the most rapid and "pythonic way

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop by [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object:

```
for i, subdf in df.groupby('Country'):
     print (i)
     print (subdf)
     #processing
```

Comment: Thanks, it's just what I was looking for. ;)